# How to specify name of string argument of web-service method

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a web-service with method signature like this:

```
public RetType doIt(String description){
   return null;
}
```

After wsdl is generated I see that (in wsdl) method `doIt` have argument name `arg0`. Is there a way in code-first approach to specify argument name to be shown in wsdl appropriately like in Java class method signature?

Comment: could you give some detail on how you generate the wsdl?

Comment: the web-service is deployed on jboss app-server, then I run http://.../services?wsdl

Answer (score 6):

If you are still using JAX-WS (like yesterday), they you can use the [`@WebParam`](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/jax-ws-ea3/docs/annotations.html#2.4%20javax.jws.WebParam|outline) annotation and its `name` attribute to control defaults in the generated WSDL:

```
public RetType doIt(@WebParam(name = "desc") String description) { 
    return null;
}
```

If you're not using JAX-WS, forget my answer. In any case, you are really, really not providing enough details to the readers on what you are doing. You need to improve the way you ask questions here on SO (and anywhere else), you need to give more information on what you are doing, on your context, on the tools you are using, provide some code (with the annotations!), etc. People can't guess all that, they don't all have a crystal ball you know. And if you are in a hurry and can't do that, I'm afraid readers won't take time to answer your questions too in the future. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I see. I'm hurrying. I'm promicing to read more rtfm. Thanks for help.

Comment: No, when I sad hurrying - I meant sometimes hurry to ask. :) Sorry for disturbing to U.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I understood :) And no, you didn't disturb me (or I wouldn't have answered).